# print empty asterisk triangle c

Tags: c, loops, printing, draw

So I've looked up and only found normal triangles questions out there.
This one is a bit tricky.

> Given a N, your program should create an asterisk unfilled triangle with a N side size.

```
Example 1 
Inform N: 1 
*

Example 2:
Inform N: 2
**
*
Example 3:
Inform N: 3
***
**
*
Example 4:
Inform N: 4
****
* *
**
*
Example 5:
Inform N: 5
*****
*  *
* *
**
*
```

Here's my attempt, I could only make a filled triangle inefficiently

```
void q39(){
    int n,i,b;
    printf("Inform N: ");
    scanf ("%i",&n);
    for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
    printf("*");
    for ( b = 1; b < n; ++b)
    {
        if (i==0)
        {
        printf("*");
        }
        else if (i==1 && b>1)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        else if (i==2 && b>2)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        else if(i==3 && b>3){
            printf("*");
        }
        else if(i==4 && b>4){
            printf("*");
        }
        else if(i==5 && b>5){
            printf("*");
        }
        else if(i==6 && b>6){
            printf("*");
        }
        else if(i==7 && b>7){
            printf("*");
        }
        else if (i==8 && b>8){
            printf("*");
        }
    }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: I have made an attempt

Comment: How about the "post the code and ask a specific question" part?

Comment: Sorry, it's just that I thought my code was too bad to show you guys, but ill post it anyway... its inefficient

Comment: How is this not specific? I have specified everything, i even showed examples of inputs and outputs!

Comment: it's not "give me the code", if at least I could get some ideas of how I should do it.... I don't know why some of you step on beginners so much here...

Comment: You print N asterisks in first line, then in each next line you print asterisk, N-k-1 spaces and one more asterisk where k is number of line until k == N-1, and then one asterisk in last line

Comment: I apologize if that is not your intention. But you need to view it from the reader's perspective. You dumped an assignment question with no attempted code and no specific question. What conclusion would you expect people to come to? Even now you still haven't asked a question. Are you saying the code is too long, or it's taking too long to run or is it just generally how can the code be better written, or...? I guess it is the latter...but just trying to explain that it is your job to make the question clear and not ours to guess.

Comment: For example, someone could answer this as "Make a loop with these parameters" which would very much help me, and then later i will be the one helping...

Comment: You seem to be conflating the task of devising an algorithm with the task of implementing an algorithm. If you've devised an algorithm, tell us what it is. If you haven't devised an algorithm, your code is very unlikely to work. It's worth taking the time to carefully write out an algorithm and convince yourself that it's correct before you start coding.

Comment: Well I know that, it was just an idea I had for the triangle, and I know this algorithm is not correct but that's the only thing i could come up with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to think that first line should be filled with `*`.
Second thing is first character of every line should be `*`.
and last character should also be `*`. and in between you need to fill spaces.

```
int main()
{
    int n=6;
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--) // using n-1, bcz loop is running upto 0
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {
            if(i==n-1 || j==0 ||i==j)
                printf("*");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");      
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The condition `if(i==n-1 || j==0 ||i==j)`
here `i==n-1` is used so that first line should be filled with `*`.
`j==0` is used to make first character of every line `*`. every time when new line starts i.e j=0 it will print one `*` character.
`i==j` this is used to make last character `*` when i==j that is last index upto which we are running loop. so at last index it will print a `*`.
And for all other values it will print space as it will run `else` condition.

**OUTPUT**

```
******
*   *
*  *
* *
**
*
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just providing you a logic , you can work upon it . 
You can take three loops. One for row say i , second for * (asterisk ) say j , and third for the white spaces ( empty triangle) say k. Now , I hope you know how to make a triangle by using i,j .
The logic for k could be it should be executed 1 less then the rows' loop(i.e. the jth one) and should print a blank space(" ").

You can divide your Problem in the modules like this

```
print_asterisk(n);
print_hollow_asterisk();
print_asterisk(1);
```

Comment: thanks, I thought maybe I could make a function that would print a line with two *(asterisks) on each side with a specified size like:
1 * *, 2 would print *  *, 3 *   * you know?

Comment: a function that takes in an integer that will be the number of spaces between 2 asterisks

Comment: @LeonardoDias Yes, there can be a number of ways to solve it.You can choose the one you like the most if the complexity doesn't matters .

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about an algorithm for printing out the triangle. There are three separate types of lines you (may) need to draw:

1. A row full of N asterisks
2. A row with an asterisk at the start, one at the end and N-2 spaces in the middle.
3. A row with 1 asterisk (which is just a subset of #1).

Step 1 - work out *how* to print out the above rows

Step 2 - work out *when* to print out the above rows

Answer (score 1):

a longer version of this problems which can be optimized a great deal

```
 void print_start_and_end_asterix( int n )
    {
            int i = 0;
            for ( ; i < n ; i ++ )
            {
                    if( i == 0 || i == n-1 )
                            printf("*");
                    else
                            printf(" ");
            }
            printf("\n");
    }


void print_full_row( int n )
{
        int i = 0;
        for ( ; i < n ; i ++ )
                printf("*");
        printf("\n");
}

int main (){
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        int row = 0 , col = n;
        for ( row = 0 ; row < n ; row ++ , col--) {
                if( row == 0 )
                        print_full_row(col);
                else
                        print_start_and_end_asterix(col);
        }


        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The triangle being drawn is a two-dimensional figure, and therefore can be drawn with two nested `for` loops. The outer loop keeps track of the row which is being drawn. The inner loop keeps track of the column. For each combination of `row` and `col`, a very simple decision must be made, shall we output an asterisk, or shall we output a space.

Begin with the outer loop. It makes sense for the outer loop to count down from N to 1, since the number of characters on a line starts at N and decreases till it reaches 1. So the outer loop is

```
for ( row = N; row >= 1; row-- )
```

Next is the inner loop. The inner loop needs to count the number of characters on each line. We've arranged things so that the `row` variable in the outer loop is equal to the number of characters. Hence, the inner loop is simply

```
for ( col = 0; col < row; col++ )
```

Now we come to the decision. Given a `row` and a `col`, shall we print an asterisk or a space? Well, we should always print an asterisk on the first line, which is where `row == N`. We should also print an asterisk on the left edge, where `col == 0`. Finally, we need an asterisk on the right edge, where `col == row-1`. Hence, the decision code is

```
if ( row == N || col == 0 || col == row-1 )  // top or left or right
    putchar( '*' );
else
    putchar( ' ' );
```

Finally, after the inner loop is finished, we need to output a newline character to start the next line

```
putchar( '\n' );
```

And that's all there is to it.