# How to print the result in diamond like this below?

Tags: c

What is the code in C to print the result in diamond like in this below: (using for loop syntax and procedure)

```
    3
   323
  32123
 321 123
321   123
 321 123
  32123
   323
    3
```

Comment: [Same as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32858331/print-empty-asterisk-triangle-c) more or less.

Answer (score 2):

Look i am not sure about the exact coding, but the way of doing these diamond problem is as follows:

Use two loops. One inside another. Outer loop will be for rows and inner loop for columns. Insert space for middle rows.

```
for (int i;i<rows.length;i++)
{ 
   for (int j;j<columns.length;j++)
   { 
      //your logic here to check where to insert space to make it diamond 
   } 
}
```

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: `for (int i;i<{rows.length};i++){

for (int j;j<{columns.length};j++){

//your logic here to check where to insert space to make it diamond

}
}`